# How to use an unassigned local variable for an abstract class object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a text_changed function for my textbox. I want my software to read a character and check if it is a sequence character '/n' . Since sequential characters are considered single characters I am trying to use TextReader.Equals('\n') but an error occurs that says

> use of unassigned local variable 'reader'

The TextReader is an abstract class . I tried to initialize it by using TextReader `reader = new TextReader` but an error occured that says i cant initialize an abstract class.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.TextReader reader;

    if(reader.Equals(null))
    {
        his_Textbox.Text = My_Textbox.Text;
    }
}
```

Please tell me what can I do to stop this error.

Comment: What is the `reader` supposed to do?

Comment: it is suppose to look for new line

Comment: Yes, look for a new line in what string?

Comment: `TextReader reader = null;` should be enough to fix error... But it is unclear what you actually trying to achieve...

Comment: I am trying to read characters simultaneously as one writes them in a text. I thought the TextChanged event makes this possible without having to declare a char variable. If i am wrong, How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize it with a concrete implementation of TextReader, like StringReader, perhaps.

Secondly, perhaps you don't understand reference types in C#. The variable is merely a reference (pointer) to an object. Without initialization, there is no object, just a empty variable.

Try:

```
using(var reader = new System.IO.StringReader(whateverText)) {
      //...
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader(v=vs.110).aspx

But depending on your needs, you may not even need a reader. Just use a regex or string API to search a textbox.

Comment: I would be careful of saying "a null variable" because it does not even have a value of `null` it is uninitialized.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - good catch, thanks. It is null for member fields, but for local variables I _think_ it is undefined. I'll revise.

Comment: Its not "null for member fields" either, it is [`default(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) for unset member fields. For classes `default(T)` just happens to be `null`.

Comment: Gosh I feel like I'm in court. For member `reference` fields it is indeed null.